# Mongo sort on a calculated condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection of messages that looks like this:

```
{
  'recipients': [],
  'unRead': [],
  'content': 'Text'
}
```

Recipients is an array of user ids, and unRead is an array of all users who have not yet opened the message. That's working as intended, but I need to query the list of all messages so that it returns the first 20 results, prioritizing the unread ones first, something like:

```
db.messages.find({recipients: {$elemMatch: userID} })
  .sort({unRead: {$elemMatch: userID}})
  .limit(20)
```

But that doesn't work. What's the best way to prioritize results based on whether they fit a certain criteria?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to "weight" results by certain criteria or have any kind of "calculated value" within a "sort", then you need the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method instead. This allows "projected" values to be used in the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) operation, for which only a present field in the document can be used:

```js
db.messages.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "messages": userId } },
    { "$project": {
        "recipients": 1,
        "unread": 1,
        "content": 1,
        "readYet": {
            "$setIsSubset": [ [userId], "$unread" ] }
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "readYet": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 20 }
])
```

Here the [`$setIsSubset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operator allows comparison of the "unread" array with a converted array of `[userId]` to see if there are any matches. The result will either be `true` where the userId exists or `false` where it does not.

This can then be passed to `$sort`, which orders the results with preference to the matches ( decending sort is `true` on top ), and finally [`$limit`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) just returns the results up to the amount specified.

So in order to use a calulated term for "sort", the value needs to be "projected" into the document so it can be sorted upon. The aggregation framework is how you do this.

Also note that `$elemMatch` is not required just to match a single value within an array, and you need only specify the value directly. It's purpose is where "multiple" conditions need to be met on a single array element, which of course does not apply here.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! The only comment I'll make is that Mongo threw an error until I changed $setIsSubSet to $setIsSubset.

Comment: @beatniknight Typical me. The documentation link was right but my camelCase brain keeps saying it's two words and keeps typing it that way.

Comment: Better to use `$in` instead of `$setIsSubset`. So: `"$in": [ userId, "$unread" ]`