# Mongoose - Sort a find depends on boolean property

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose find request, and I have a first mongoose schema who contains this (the client) :

```
client: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Client' },
```

And I have the client schema :

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  company: String,
  companyAsPrimaryName: Boolean,
})
```

I want to do a find request in the first schema depends on the client property companyAsPrimaryName boolean.
If it's false : I want to sort on firstName + lastName, and if it's true, I want to sort on company.

I have no idea how to do this, I already checked an answer and I found nothing.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do these answers help you?: [_Mongo sort on a calculated condition_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32958402/996081) and [_Mongodb conditional sort_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159417/mongodb-conditional-sort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use `aggregate` with `$addFields` and `$cond` to create a field with the name you want to sort by, then sort by that field. The following snippet will get every `Foo` and sort them according to either the company name or first name + last name if `companyAsPrimaryName` is false.

```
  const data = await Foo.aggregate([
  {
    // basically .populate('client') in our case
    $lookup: {
      from: 'clients',
      localField: 'client',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'client'
    }
  },
  {
    // deconstruct the client array into one object
    $unwind: '$client'
  },
  {
    // add a computed field for sorting
    $addFields: {
      sortName: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: ['$client.companyAsPrimaryName', true]
          },
          then: '$client.company',
          else: {
            $concat: ['$client.firstName', '$client.lastName']
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortName: 1
    }
  }
])
console.log(data)
```

Here `Foo` is the model containing the `client` as a field. Note that this will however include that field in the result. If you want to omit some fields, you can add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to pick the fields.

Here's a snippet I used to test this out locally:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Client = mongoose.model('Client', {
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  company: String,
  companyAsPrimaryName: Boolean
})

const Foo = mongoose.model('Foo', {
  name: String,
  client: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client' }
})

// Call this in `start()` to populate some sample data
const create = async () => {
  const client1 = await new Client({
    firstName: 'Alpha',
    lastName: 'Alphaname',
    company: 'Alphabet',
    companyAsPrimaryName: true
  }).save()
  const client2 = await new Client({
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Wayne',
    company: 'Google',
    companyAsPrimaryName: true
  }).save()
  const client3 = await new Client({
    firstName: 'Bravo',
    lastName: 'Bretty',
    company: 'Zulu Solutions',
    companyAsPrimaryName: false
  }).save()

  await new Foo({
    name: 'Toaster',
    client: client1
  }).save()
  await new Foo({
    name: 'Lunchbox',
    client: client1
  }).save()
  await new Foo({
    name: 'Treadmill',
    client: client1
  }).save()

  await new Foo({
    name: 'Tapas',
    client: client2
  }).save()
  await new Foo({
    name: 'Ananas',
    client: client2
  }).save()
  await new Foo({
    name: 'Zapiers',
    client: client2
  }).save()

  await new Foo({
    name: 'Brets',
    client: client3
  }).save()
  await new Foo({
    name: 'Xrats',
    client: client3
  }).save()
  await new Foo({
    name: 'Abins',
    client: client3
  }).save()
}

const start = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://CONNECTION STRING HERE', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })

  const data = await Foo.aggregate([
    {
      // basically .populate('client') in our case
      $lookup: {
        from: 'clients',
        localField: 'client',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'client'
      }
    },
    {
      // deconstruct the client array into one object
      $unwind: '$client'
    },
    {
      // add a computed field for sorting
      $addFields: {
        sortName: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: ['$client.companyAsPrimaryName', true]
            },
            then: '$client.company',
            else: {
              $concat: ['$client.firstName', '$client.lastName']
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        sortName: 1
      }
    }
  ])
  console.log(data)
}

start().then(() => {
  console.log('ready')
  mongoose.disconnect()
})
```